# Run JUnit test in IntelliJ IDEA 14 without choosing configuration type

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-14

In IntelliJ IDEA 14 with Gradle plugin I would like to run JUnit test without being asked about configuration type. Problem occurs when I run test for the first time - there is no configuration for this run. I never run tests with Gradle in IDE so it would be acceptable to disable running test with Gradle. How to run JUnit test directly?

[image: IntelliJ IDEA 14 - run test]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get rid of this annoying by adding

```
idea.gradle.prefer.idea_test_runner=true
```

to idea.properties file located in the bin directory of the IntelliJ IDEA installation. Then restart IDEA and enjoy.

Comment: @Bohemian this option was introduced in 14.1.x, update your IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: @marcin yes, thank you for letting me know. I upgraded to 14.1.x and it works! Actually, I socialised it with my team members and they all love me now :)

Answer (score 11):

Go to setting > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Runner and choose "Platform Test Runner" in "Run test using"

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer, as it gives you total control without having to modify obscure configuration files manually

Answer (score 2):

The Gradle Test Runner configuration looks a bit different in **IntelliJ 2019.2** :

[image]

To have Intellij rather than Gradle run your tests when you right-click on the test/Test Class/Test package select **IntelliJ IDEA** for the "Run tests using:" option.

Having IntelliJ run your test means that a Junit configuration is created to run the test.

When I upgraded IntelliJ 2019.1 to 2019.2 I found that the default setting for the Gradle runner was set to 'Gradle' which meant that my unit tests didn't run properly  when I right-clicked on a test and selected 'Run' - they just terminated with no results. I had to change the "Run tests using:" option to **IntelliJ IDEA**