# Run Gradle test and not Junit test in IntelliJ IDEA 15 when choosing configuration type to run with

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, junit, intellij-15

[image: I want this feature back]
I updated to Intellij 15.02 from 14 and wanted to run my tests using Gradle not JUnit, but I'm not getting the options anymore like the image you see here.

I want to be able to choose configuration type.

The thing that is happening now when I run a test is that it runs it as a JUnit test by default.

I have imported the gradle project with gradle by selecting the gradle file in the project.
I have deleted each configuration entry at the top so everything is clean and empty when running a new test with Spock.

My current "fix" is to manually create a new config entry for the gradle test. Intellij is not intelligent enough to create that same Junit test as a Gralde test.

I'm confused.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found the solution.
They have changed the way you select this option in the new version of intellij 15.02.

You have to select Gradle Test Runner.

Please take a look:
[image]

Comment: Do you have this working with 2016?  I don't have the drop-down option and changing this setting doesn't seem to have an impact.

Comment: 2016.1.3 also works. If not, refreshing Gradle helps. However. Android Studio 2.1 won't work and it's of no use to change the runner.

Comment: I can confirm that IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 ignores this setting if you have a mixed Gradle project having Java & Android subprojects.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Not working in 2018.1.4. Opened a bug on their ticketing system: https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-191291

Comment: Actually, this is a problem only with Scalatest (JUnit runner works fine and delegates the work to Gradle).

Comment: It works for me for a java test in 2018.1. When running with JUnit runner, it fails. I adjusted to "Let me choose per test", and press ALT+SHIFT+F10 and selected the Gradle configuration for one specific test, and then the test passed.

Comment: The Gradle runner configuration setup is a bit different in IntelliJ 2019.2 - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57751353/3059685

Comment: This worked for me! Now the location in settings is `Build, Execution, Deployment >> Build Tools >> Gradle`. I set the field `Build and run using:` to `Gradle`.

Answer (score 23):

In modern versions of IntelliJ (I have Ultimate 2019.2.3) here's what you need to update:
[image: change gradle settings]

Update from "Gradle" to "IntelliJ IDEA"

Comment: I wonder why they use gradle by default. It is slower and provides less options in the configuration dialog..

Comment: works flawlessly faster @Adolfo